# How Bot-Detection Works on AXS.com?

Tags: authentication, security, bots, content-security-policy

I need to understand how exactly works the bot-detection works on axs.com as I'm accessing many times this website and after a short while the login does not work any more and website is basically blocked.

By analyzing the network request and console I can see the following after clicking the login button:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.axs.com/proxy/v3/flash/migrate/authenticate?access_token=4f2be33d835e7197e245c54ff00e5fb4&region=1&locale=en-US' from origin 'https://www.axs.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:

- Using multiple VPNs to change IP address (Failed)
- Using an EC2 instance (failed)
- Using Extension called "Trace" to completely delete all my trackable data and delete cookies (Failed)
- Incognito window (Failed)
- Proxy Server Paid and Free (Failed)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution, it was needed only a better quality proxy. My steps:

1. At the beginning we used rotating proxy with brightdata from many different countries, but no luck with it.
2. Then we tried different proxy providers but always rotating, residential and mobile were tested. Again no luck.
3. We purchased US proxy from https://www.proxyrack.com/ and finally it worked. I guess the proxy quality is of vital importance. AXS security must have a pretty long blacklist for IP addresses.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on this? Which proxy you have used or what are the steps you have performed we are facing the same issue